# jQuery: Focus on / off text field with same button

Tags: jquery, button, focus, toggle

(my first time posting here so hope this is ok!)

I currently have a hidden div containing a search field, and have a button that slides the div down to make it visible, and when clicked again slides the div up to hide it from sight again.

I've also set it up so that when the button is clicked, the search textfield is selected (so the visitor doesn't have to click it - they can just type and hit enter to search, saving any more clicks).

However, when the div disappears, the text field is reselected. This isn't a problem on Chrome, but on Safari even after the div has been hidden, hitting enter still works and starts the search (no more text can be entered, however). It's also an issue on mobile, as the keyboard is brought back up, though there's nowhere to type.

Is there a way to "toggle" whether or not the text field is selected, similar to the appearance / disappearance? Or for it just to happen when the div appears, perhaps? I'm fairly new to jQuery, so any help appreciated.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showsearch').click(function() {
            $('.search-menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});             
});

jQuery(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showsearch').click(function() {
            $(".search-field").focus()
    });
});
});
```

(Where #showsearch is the button, .search-menu is the div, and .search-field is the textfield)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, virtual keyboard on mobile safari should show up

```
jQuery(function ($) { 
    $('#showsearch').click(function() {
        var searchMenu = $('.search-menu'),
            isHidden = searchMenu.is(':hidden');

        searchMenu.slideToggle('fast');

        if (isHidden){
            $('.search-field').focus();
        }
    });       
});
```

Comment: That's worked perfectly, thanks! What was stopping the iOS keyboard from appearing with the other solution?

Comment: @vaatikaiba Focus should be directly inside code, triggered by user action(click handler). If focus is inside callback, setTimeout, etc.. keyboard will not show up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following snippet instead:

```
jQuery(function ($) { //this is already fired on document ready, no need other ready handler
    $('#showsearch').click(function() {
        $('.search-menu').slideToggle("fast", function(){
            if($(this).is(':visible'))
               $(this).find(".search-field").focus(); //that supposes .search-field is wrapped inside .search-menu
        });
    });       
});
```

Comment: That's worked perfectly for the desktop Safari. However, the iOS keyboard now doesn't open up when the div opens up - is this normal? Is the 'visible' check not compatible with the iOS browser?